# Apache forwarding everything to Tomcat except webmail

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, webmail, ajp

Just asked on StackOverflow, but more appropriate here.

I have my Apache HTTP server set up to forward all requests to Tomcat, i.e. proxy_ajp.conf looks like:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

where Tomcat is listening on port 8009.  This works find except when I try to access squirrelmail (i.e. webmail) on the server.  Is there a way to forward all requests to Tomcat **except** those going to /webmail/?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ProxyPass /webmail !
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  I do this for web apps where I don't want people snooping in WEB-INF.

```
  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009 /

  <Proxy />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
  </Proxy>

  <Proxy /webmail>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
  </Proxy>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually hoping to still let request to webmail go through.  They just wouldn't go to Tomcat.

Someone on StackOverflow suggested this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond REQUEST_URI !^/webmail*
RewriteRule / /tomcat/

<Location /tomcat>
     ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8099/
</Location>

but the rewrite rule doesn't seem to be kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

A second proxy pass for /webmail ahead of the proxy pass for / may work.  I believe they are matched in order.